# puppeteer truncating referer header

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, http-referer

The following code is sending the wrong header. The 'https://bloodcurdling-alien-85469.herokuapp.com/http-tools' prints the headers of the request it is receiving. The header sent to the server is 'https://cor.goo.com/' instead of the full URL. If you change the header to something other than 'referer' not truncation is done.

```
var page, browser

browser = await puppeteer.launch();
page = await browser.newPage();
await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({'referer':'https://cor.goo.com/ffffff/ssss/wwwwwwww'})
await page.goto('https://bloodcurdling-alien-85469.herokuapp.com/http-tools')
await page.screenshot({ path: 'snap.png' });
await browser.close();
```

Is it an intended behavior of puppeteer? is there a workaround or does someone know where this is implemented in the puppeteer?

thank you